# Как задать id странице Word Press?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<a href="about.php" target="_blank" class="footer-nav__link"></a>
```

Вот есть страничка about.php как ей задать id ?

Чтобы потом использовать `<?php echo get_page_link( $page_id ); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID - это [автоматически генерируемое значение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87). Задать его нельзя. Можно только узнать/получить.

А если "about.php" - это вручную созданный файл, то он вообще не имеет никакого отношения к ВП и  соответственно никакого ID.